# Cannot get nuget feed to work with VS2015 Update 1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nugetgallery

I cannot seem to get the nuget.org feed to work correctly with VS2015

Performed the following
Clean install of Windows 10
Clean install of VS2015 Update 1
using Nuget Package Manager 3.3

Trying to configure the Nuget.org feed in VS by adding with the following URL    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

result in an error message

"A connection to the server could not be established because the following error occurred.

Could not determine the protocol used for this gallery.   The URL must point to an Atom Feed or Sharepoint List configured for hosting Visual Studio Extensions."

This would appear to be the url provided on nuget.org and 3.3 would appear to be the latest version.

Any ideas on what could be going on - this is absolutely a clean machine from scratch so nothing else has been installed or configured other than the above products.

Comment: Have you tried loading the url in a browser to verify it loads the json? Are you behind a proxy (at work)? The url is right, I've just checked my own settings.